# Using the constant-gas volume thermometer?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

My copy of "Resnick and Halliday" states that

> "We measure an unknown temperature as follows: Fill the thermometer bulb with an arbitrary amount of *any* gas and measure its pressure at the triple point of water($p3$) and its pressure at the temperature we are interested in measuring($p$), keeping the volume of the gas in the bulb constant. Calculate the ratio $p/p3$. Then repeat both measurements by a smaller amount of gas, until you can **extrapolate to the ratio $p/p3$ that you would find if there were approximately no gas in the bulb**. Calculate the temperature T by substituting this extrapolated ratio in the equation $T$=$273.16K[lt. gas→0 (p/p3)]$

My doubt is this; exactly what do they mean by the sentence that I have marked in bold? How to extrapolate this ratio?

**Edit**: Please note that I have only just graduated high school. Additionally, here is a picture of the graph of the temperature against pressure(at triple point of water) for various gases, as given in the book:

[image: graph]

Please help. Much thanks in advance :) Regards.

Comment: Hi Kaumudi, this is just my guess, but by extrapolate i think they mean,  follow the procedure they give in the question, take measurements every time you do that and plot them on a graph that you should be able to extend to the point they describe, with no gas in the bulb.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check :)

Comment: @CountTo10: So is this graphical extrapolation what they mean? To measure enough values of $p$ and $p3$ to be able to draw a graph and then extrapolate it? Why should we measure it so many times? Won't two points be sufficient for extrapolation(since pressure varies **linearly** with temperature)?

Comment: Well, its years (and years) since I did this, but as we both know the word extrapolate means go from what you know  to your best guess. Sorry, but that's all I can think of with this problem. You might be extrapolating yourself right now based on graphs you know are linear to this one...........try it, see how it really turns out. Best of luck with it.